# Can you change the position of the email address attribute in an Azure ADB2C User Flow?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am creating an ADB2C user flow for a user sign up page. I want to capture given name, surname, job title and email address.  Currently with those attributes selected, when I navigate to the page layout I see the following:

[image]

When I try to edit the order of the attributes, and move the email address to the bottom and hit save, Azure displays a success message that my changes have been saved, however the email address attribute is moved back to the top of the list.

I'd like to achieve this:
[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Email Address will always to default to the top of the list. Try with other attributes.